# What is better conditional expressions or a if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements

I was reading an article that was talking about conditional javascript but they didn't explain which was better to use. I made a fiddle with the 2 examples.

```
console.log('start');

const VALUE = true;
const TEST = false;

//test 1
VALUE && !TEST && (() => {
    console.log('hello there!');
})();

//test 2
if(VALUE && !TEST) {
    console.log('bye');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xvdLq6to

The most important thing with this example is that I don't want to call a new function I want to execute the code in the function its inside just like an if statement. If you know something better then I can't wait to hear that!

Here is the article (keep in mind that the example is not directly from the article) 
https://hackernoon.com/conditional-javascript-for-experts-d2aa456ef67c

Comment: The `if` looks far better IMO, using a construct that results in an expression (including the conditional operator) are probably best used when you need the *result of the expression*. If you're just using boolean logic, use `if` / `else`

Comment: Agreed with @CertainPerformance. I've never seen the "test 1" kind used anywhere, and don't know what its benefit would be.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother with the syntax shown in test 1. Readability of your code should be higher priority here. Also a tool like an uglifier or minifier can probably generate code pretty similar to test 1 for you automatically while not sacrificing readability.

Comment: If you're worried about the function, don't be, just leave it off entirely `VALUE && !TEST && console.log('hello there!');`

Comment: Can you please link the article that you read?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah this is just an example I would want to use this with multiple lines of code inside not only the log ;)

Comment: @Bergi I linked the article in the question above

Comment: @Bergi I would also like to clarify why this is not a duplicate the big difference here is the anonymous function. This is more a ''alternative" of an if statement inside the function instead of calling another function what happens in the other question.

Comment: You say they weren't explaining which was better to use, but I can find "*you will see how some conditional statements can be converted to simple expressions. You will also see how such conversions can make your code look more compact and cleaner.*" Of course, many would disagree - `if` is much more readable for a statement with a side effect. Yes, they can shorten it, but the article is called "*conditionals for experts*" not "for minifiers". It only makes sense when you want to produce a value (typically with a ternary).

Comment: @RickGrendel The IIFE doesn't really make a difference - it's just another expression to be evaluated. And it doesn't make the code better anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example should be the preferred syntax, *by far*. Readability is incredibly important and the second example is considerably more readable, it's easier to understand the intention of the code.

The first example, while technically possible, is simply not *good* code, in my opinion.